# How to send CSS to the client using HTTP response headers?

Tags: css, http-headers

How to send a CSS file to the client using server headers?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: You'll need to provide a hell of a lot more information than this.

Comment: I want to hide html code

Comment: looking to this page http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/css-without-html

Comment: @Jasilan, try to re-phrase your qustion wiht more information, which languages are you using, what have you tried, what is it exactly you want to do? :)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks, @Pekka: This link he provided is very very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not very descriptive, but you are probably ***refering to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-without-html/)*** which was recently posted online.

It really is not that hard: [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) describes the `LINK` header, which allows you to send `<link>` elements through HTTP headers instead of including them in the HTML.

Like the example in the article, **usage is similiar to this**:

```
Link: <some-document.html>;rel=prefetch
```

...which would have the same effect as placing this in your HTML:

```
<link href="some-document.html" rel="prefetch"
```

When using a language like **PHP**, you would have to write a line of code similiar to this:

```
<?php header('Link: <demo.css>;rel=stylesheet');
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** ***only FireFox and Opera seem to support this header at the time of writing.***